# How to change the defaults for screen mode in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am using Photoshop CS5 on Mac. I prefer to use "Full screen mode with menu bar" rather than "Standard screen mode". Is there a way to have Photoshop remember my favorite screen mode settings and use them as defaults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://christopherpreece.com/blog/:

> You can automate this feature if you want images to open in a specific screen mode. Make a new action, select Insert Menu Item from the Actions panel menu, go to `View->Screen Mode` and select the screen mode you want to switch to, click OK and then stop recording.
>
> Go to `File->Scripts->Script Events Manager`, click on the Enable checkbox up top, set the Event dropdown to Open Document, select the Action radio button and then select the action that you just made and click on Add. If you want, you can also do this for when you make a new document, just set the Event dropdown to New Document and then click on Add again.

Adobe says it all:

- [Change the screen mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-74dea.html)

Hope this will help....

Answer (score 2):

I just found this post and thought I would share. Basically you go under Window in Photoshop and make sure Application Frame is checked. That's it, problem solved!

http://www.saelstrom.com/blog/photoshop-cs5-mac-vs-pc-tips/

Answer (score 1):

The preference file is located:

```
Users/[user name]/Library/Preferences/Adobe Photoshop CS5 Settings
```

You may be able to modify this manually to achieve the settings you like.

More info here:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/828/cpsid_82893.html

Comment: Welcome to photo stack exchange, thank you for the contribution, that sounds like a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=458002):

> "You set it by clicking the Change Screen Mode button on the tool bar
>   (its the last button at the bottom) or pressing the F key. There's a
>   little arrow on the tool that open a flyout menu from which you can
>   select either screen mode; it then becomes "sticky" so Photoshop
>   remembers when you reopen it."

Unfortunately I don't have Photoshop CS5 available to test if this actually works.

Comment: Just tried that, didn't work (didn't become "sticky"). I guess it is not possible at least in this version since you cannot go to the full screen mode unless you have an image loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt look like you can set it for a default but if you pull up an image you can press the f key to cycle through all of the screen modes which prevents you from having to use the drop down menu every time.

Answer (score -1):

Go to window > Application Frame (make sure Application Frame is checked)...DONE :)

Comment: Perhaps it would be good to add a screen shot to show what to do?  BTW: Welcome to GD.SE!